# Question on inequalities. How to show if $a+b+c+d+e\le r+s+t+u+v$ and $a-r\ge0, b-s\ge0,c-t\ge0,d-u\ge0,e-v\ge0$ implies $a=r, b=s,c=t,d=u,e=v$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

Question on inequalities.

How to show if :
$a+b+c+d+e\leq r+s+t+u+v$ and $a-r \geq 0, b-s \geq 0,c-t \geq 0,d-u \geq 0,e-v \geq 0$,

then $a=r, b=s,c=t,d=u,e=v$. How do you show this is true. I can see it is obviously true but how can you show it.

Answer (score 0):

$$a-r \geq 0$$ 
$$b-s \geq 0$$
$$c-t \geq 0$$
$$d-u \geq 0$$
$$e-v \geq 0$$
Adding all the inequalities gives you:
$$a+b+c+d+e \geq r+s+t+u+v$$ 
Also given:
$$a+b+c+d+e\leq r+s+t+u+v$$
So only possibility will be:
$$a+b+c+d+e = r+s+t+u+v$$ 
$$(a-r)+(b-s)+(c-t)+(d-u)+(e-v)=0$$
Each of the brackets from the above equality must be equal to $0$ from the $5$ conditions at the top.Hence:
$$a=r,b=s,c=t,d=u,e=v$$

Answer (score 0):

By the first inequality, we have
$$(a-r)+(b-s)+(c-t)+(d-u)+(e-v)\le 0.$$
On the other hand, by the other inequalities, we have
$$(a-r)+(b-s)+(c-t)+(d-u)+(e-v)\ge 0.$$

Hence, we have
$$(a-r)+(b-s)+(c-t)+(d-u)+(e-v)=0.$$

Here, since each $()$ is either $0$ or positive, each $()$ has to be $0$. 
(This is because the right hand side is $0$. If at least one of these is positive, the right hand side has to be positive. This is a contradiction.)

Hence, we have
$$a=r, b=s, c=t, d=u, e=v.$$

**Q.E.D.**